# Cannot verify Contract - bytecode has small difference

Tags: etherscan, bytecode, verify

I forgot to verify the ERC20 token contract after deploying it. Now after 5 months, Im doing it again and completely forget which compiler and if I accidently change anything on the code.

After playing with Remix, I found out I use v0.5.11 as the Bold hex text 0b mean 11 in decimal. You can see the ByteCode almost the same, except the hex in BOLD. This is the very end of the whole Bytecode. Please help if you have any clue.

ByteCode expected:
......
6f6d20746865207a65726f206164647265737345524332303a2064656372656173656420616c6c6f77616e63652062656c6f77207a65726fa265627a7a72315820**55d977d29270099c12d5a11dea2a02d7991cc2c05448c6bd893bc1564278a96a**64736f6c63430005**0b**0032526f6c65733a206163636f756e7420697320746865207a65726f2061646472657373

ByteCode compiled from Remix:
......
6f6d20746865207a65726f206164647265737345524332303a2064656372656173656420616c6c6f77616e63652062656c6f77207a65726fa265627a7a72315820**3fb4a2175649a2bc0e44a5cac18a7cafc7728139b46c3c1922298c8a2df8a0ab**64736f6c63430005**0b**0032526f6c65733a206163636f756e7420697320746865207a65726f2061646472657373

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see what happens here.

In solidity v0.5.11, the end of the bytecode includes the following :

0xa2

0x65

627a7a7231 => "bzzr1" in hex

0x58

0x20

**<32 bytes swarm hash>**

0x64

736f6c63 -> "solc" in hex

0x43

<3 byte version encoding>

0x00

0x32

That's exactly what you have.
In your two bytecodes **55d977d29270099c12d5a11dea2a02d7991cc2c05448c6bd893bc1564278a96a** and **3fb4a2175649a2bc0e44a5cac18a7cafc7728139b46c3c1922298c8a2df8a0ab** are 32 bytes swarm hash, also called **metadata**. The metadata part differs according to the development environment and has no impact on the smart contract code. Therefore the two bytecodes match the same smart contract, you are good.

Note that the part after 0x0032 (**526f6c65733a206163636f756e7420697320746865207a65726f2061646472657373**) refers to the constructor arguments. Indeed, your two bytecodes are **creation bytecodes** passed as the data parameter of the deployment transaction. The **runtime (or deployed) bytecode** results from the creation bytecode and does not include the constructor part.

Comment: thanks alot Its really helpful